# Can we concate two columns in GROUP BY condition in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am wondering if we possible had something like below:

```
 SELECT Variable1, Variable2, ...
 FROM MyDB.MyTable
 GROUP BY ( CONCATENATE (  Variable1 AND Variable2 ) )
```

To get a result like:

```
 Variable1, Variable2, Variable1 and Variable2
```

Comment: what does it mean ? What is your requirement ?

Comment: In ANSI SQL, no, that's not allowed. But the GROUP BY makes no sense without aggregate functions. Show us some sample table data, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want by simply grouping by `Variable1, Variable2` but you would need to select the columns you intend to concantenate. So this would work:

```
SELECT Variable1, Variable2, concat(Variable1 , Variable2), AggregatedColumn
FROM MyDB.MyTable
GROUP BY Variable1, Variable2
```

......assuming `Variable1` and `Variable2` are column names of course.

The general rule is that you need to have the minimal building blocks of every constituent except those included in aggregate functions within your `group by`. So .....

```
SELECT concat(Variable1 , Variable2), AggregatedColumn
FROM MyDB.MyTable
GROUP BY concat(Variable1 , Variable2)
```

...would also work since you just required the concatenated value as a non-aggregated column in the ouput, but....

```
SELECT Variable1, Variable2, concat(Variable1 , Variable2), AggregatedColumn
FROM MyDB.MyTable
GROUP BY concat(Variable1 , Variable2)
```

would not since it's expecting `Variable1` and `Variable2` in the `group by`.

On a side note, you could just as well use `Variable1 + Variable2` instead of `concat(Variable1 , Variable2)`.

*EDIT: per @jarlh's comment below, `GROUP BY concat(Variable1 , Variable2)` isn't valid ANSI-SQL and this shouldn't be used and I'm seeing why too. If `Varaible1` and `Variable2` were `ash` and `win` it would group it in the same group as if they were `as` and `hwin` or `ashwi` and `n` even though, most probably, these should be different groups.*

Comment: `GROUP BY concat(Variable1 , Variable2)` is actually not valid ANSI SQL. The GROUP BY clause may only list columns.

Comment: My recommended answer was `GROUP BY Variable1, Variable2 `, The other option is just another possibility. Grouping by a projection of one or more columns works with most major DBMSs. What documentation are you referring to when you say 'The GROUP BY clause may only list columns' ?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9075-2:2011(E), i.e. the ISO/ANSI SQL specification. (The ANSI SQL compliant trick is to do the concat part in a derived table, and then do group by on it's result.)

Comment: @jarlh, I can see why this might cause problems and have edited my answer to reflect this.